# How to verify svn to git conversion?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, version-control-migration

What checks do you perform after the svn-to-git to make sure you have all tags/branches/commits etc. as they were on svn and nothing is lost?

Checks I can think of is:

1. Number and names of git remote branches match svn branches
2. Number and names of tags match svn tags
3. Number of commits on each branch are the same in both repositories

Could you guide me and suggest any other checks? Are there any tools/scripts you are aware of that may be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also check that any `svn:ignore` settings you had in place in the SVN repo were converted to `.gitignore` entries. You can create `.gitignore` files using [git svn create-ignore](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html):

```
$ git svn create-ignore
```

Or, if you prefer not to use `.gitignore` files (which are shared among all repo collaborators) you can put the same rules in your local repo's [`.git/info/exclude`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) file:

```
$ git svn show-ignore > .git/info/exclude
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check that the number of files and directories match in both SVN and Git repos. Sometimes, during conversion, the empty directories in SVN are not created in Git.